# Add all dependencies, but NoClassDefFoundError com/intellij/uiDesigner/core/GridLayoutManager

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I using Swing GUI Form in my program. In IntelliJ IDEA **all work fine**, but after packaging via Maven I get the error:

> C:\Work\Idea\XLSConfigurdator\target>java -jar
>   xlsconfigurdator-parent-1.0.jar. Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/uiDesign
>   er/core/GridLayoutManager
>           at XLSCreator.$$$setupUI$$$(XLSCreator.java)
>           at XLSCreator.(XLSCreator.java:24)
>           at XLSCreator.main(XLSCreator.java:73) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLa
>   youtManager
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 3 more
>
> C:\Work\Idea\XLSConfigurdator\target>java -jar
>   xlsconfigurdator-parent-1.0.jar Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/uiDesign
>   er/core/GridLayoutManager
>           at XLSCreator.$$$setupUI$$$(XLSCreator.java)
>           at XLSCreator.(XLSCreator.java:24)
>           at XLSCreator.main(XLSCreator.java:73) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLa
>   youtManager
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 3 more

"main" method only run constructor of class, constructor configured GUI Form via $$$setupUI$$$() method (File - Settings - Generate GUI into: Java source code).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new XLSCreator();

    sourceClass sc = new sourceClass();
    array = sc.readFromExcel(fileName);
}

public XLSCreator() {
    $$$setupUI$$$();
    setContentPane(rootPanel);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500, 200);
    setTitle("I'll save your mistakes");

    aceptButton.addActionListener(this);
**etc**
...
}
```

I read all topics about this error, I added all dependencies into pom.xml (poi, poi-ooxml, swingx, forms_rt, ideauidesigner-maven-plugin, junit, forms, javac2), all needed plugins (maven-jar-plugin, ideauidesigner-maven-plugin) but still have problem with GridLayoutManager after packagin.

Comment: Is the space at `uiDesign er`correct and have you tried after you removed it?

Comment: That you define the dependencies in you pom, doesnt mean that they are on classpath when you run the delivered release. In the IDE's the workspace is in classpath and with maven, the maven repo is in classpath. You need configure your classpath.

Comment: You may have an older version of `forms_rt.jar` in the classpath. Try the one from `IDEA_HOME/redist`.

Comment: Open the generated fat JAR and see if you can find the JAR that contains that class.  If you can't see it the JVM won't be able to, either.  You have a packaging issue.

Comment: How i need configure my classpath?
I use latest version of forms_rt.jar and into my .jar file i see only my classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all, you are best.

But I forgot paste into pom.xml maven-compiler-plugin and configure it

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>      
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>XLSCreator</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```